# Pandas crosstab plot - how to show values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                   'city':['Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Lyon','Dax','Dax','Lyon','Lyon','Lyon'],
                   'type':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','B','A','B','B'],
                   'val':[100,90,95,95,90,75,100,70,75,90,95,85]})
```

And I want to create a line plot where to show the percentage of type per grouped city, and to see the numerical value on each point on the line.

I have tried this:

```
pd.crosstab(df['city'],df['type'],normalize = 'index').plot(marker = 'x)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I can't figure how to put the data labels. I attached a pic of my intended plot:
[image]

Please, any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add them by using matplotlib's [plt.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

i think it's best to separate the plot from the data-calculation...
it makes everything is much clearer!

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                   'city':['Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Pau','Lyon','Dax','Dax','Lyon','Lyon','Lyon'],
                   'type':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','B','A','B','B'],
                   'val':[100,90,95,95,90,75,100,70,75,90,95,85]})

ct = pd.crosstab(df['city'], df['type'], normalize='index')

ax = ct.plot(figsize=(9, 6))

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(ct.iterrows()):
    ax.text(x=i, y=y.A, s=f"{round(y.A*100)}%")
    ax.text(x=i, y=y.B, s=f"{round(y.B*100)}%")
```

[image]